# Display Footer in my emails

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to display a footer in all my emails with the feature "Header & Footer" (Email > Admin > Account Settings).
I put a Custom footer like :

```
<p>My Footer</p>
```

but nothing is displayed in my Emails. I tried to create an (almost) empty HTML email, and nothing neither.

Do you know what I can have a look to ?
Note that CAN SPAM business rule is deactivated for us.

Thanks for your help !

David

Comment: <custom type="footer" />   https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&id=sf.mc_overview_headers_and_footers.htm&type=5

Comment: Hi EazyE, I saw this doc but for me it was only for Custom Templates. I might be wrong.
But if I put this code in the Custom Footer section, nothing is displayed:
<custom type="footer" />
<p>My text</p>

Comment: Hi again, Salesforce support told me the header and footer section can be used only if we use templates. 
I don't see any way to to add a code to every email going out from marketing cloud if we're using HTML emails, without editing every email before...

Comment: You would have to create a template or add the html code i provided in every email